# Pivot with dynamic columns

Tags: sql

There are 4 tables:

- **Suppl**, fields: (Code_name, Code_name_arch, Tasknum, Pki_num, Group_eng, Name, Descr, Cost, Quan, shop);
- **Maker**, fields : (Code_maker, Code_maker_arch, Code_name, provider);
- **Arrival**, fields: (Code_arr, Code_maker, quan_arr);
- **Accounts**, fields: (Code_acc, Code_maker, num_acc, quan_acc, summ)

my query is:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[pr_tblz] As
Set NOCOUNT ON
Declare @task VARCHAR(4000)
Select @task = coalesce(@task + ',[' + [Tasknum] + ']',
'[' + [Tasknum] + ']')
FROM [db_pki].[dbo].[Suppl]
Group BY [Tasknum]
Order BY [Tasknum]
Declare @query VARCHAR(8000)
Set @query='
Alter View Amountzz As
SELECT Shop, Name, Desc, Group_eng as GI, '+ @task +', quan_arr As specif, quan_acc As acns 
FROM 
(
select
Shop, Name, Desc, Group_eng, Tasknum, Quan, quan_arr, quan_acc
from [db_pki].[dbo].[Suppl] as deliveries
LEFT JOIN [db_pki].[dbo].[Maker] ON (deliveries.[Code_name] = [db_pki].[dbo].[Maker].[Code_name])
LEFT JOIN [db_pki].[dbo].[Arrival] ON ([db_pki].[dbo].[Maker].[Code_maker] = [db_pki].[dbo].[Arrival].[Code_maker])
LEFT JOIN [db_pki].[dbo].[Accounts] ON ([db_pki].[dbo].[Maker].[Code_maker] = [db_pki].[dbo].[Accounts].[Code_maker])
)date_to_pivot
PIVOT 
(
Max([Quan])
For [Tasknum]
IN (' + @task + ')
 )AS p'
Execute (@query)
```

result:

```
Shop      Name     Descr    GI    n1     n2      n3 ...    specif    acns
1         name1      1       5    4                           1        1
2 10      name2      2       3    8                           2        2
3         name3      3       501         11                   3        3
1 8       name1      1       5           16                   7        10
a 2 10    name2      2       3                   3            5        6
5         name1      1       2                   5            6        3
```

How can I get the following result?

```
Shop      Name     Descr    GI    n1     n2      n3 ...    specif    acns
1 8       name1      1       5    4      16                 8(1+7)     11
a 2 10    name2      2       3    8              3            7        8(2+6)
3         name3      3      501          11                   3        3
5         name1      1       2                   5            6        3
```

n1, n2, n3,... - Tasknum

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve with your new result?

Comment: I want to group rows, as shown in the picture below. In the field "Shop" for grouped items distinct values ​​should follow a space. The fields "specif" and "acns" for the names with the same designation and a group of engineers (GI) to calculate the amount (values ​​are taken from the related tables "Arrival" and "Accounts"). Task numbers (n1, n2, ...) for grouped items must be in the same line.

Comment: sorry for the translator

Comment: How to calculate then sum for the distinct items( by fields "specif" and "acns")&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not tested.** Try aggregating the values of `Shop`, `specif` and `acns` in the subselect that pulls the columns before the pivoting, like this (the necessary changes are highlighted in bold):

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[pr_tblz] As
Set NOCOUNT ON
Declare @task VARCHAR(4000)
Select @task = coalesce(@task + ',[' + [Tasknum] + ']',
'[' + [Tasknum] + ']')
FROM [db_pki].[dbo].[Suppl]
Group BY [Tasknum]
Order BY [Tasknum]
Declare @query VARCHAR(8000)
Set @query='
Alter View Amountzz As
SELECT Shop, Name, Desc, Group_eng as GI, '+ @task +', quan_arr As specif, quan_acc As acns 
FROM 
(
select
MAX(Shop    ) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS Shop,
Name, Desc, Group_eng, Tasknum, Quan,
SUM(quan_arr) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS quan_arr,
SUM(quan_acc) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS quan_acc
from [db_pki].[dbo].[Suppl] as deliveries
LEFT JOIN [db_pki].[dbo].[Maker] ON (deliveries.[Code_name] = [db_pki].[dbo].[Maker].[Code_name])
LEFT JOIN [db_pki].[dbo].[Arrival] ON ([db_pki].[dbo].[Maker].[Code_maker] = [db_pki].[dbo].[Arrival].[Code_maker])
LEFT JOIN [db_pki].[dbo].[Accounts] ON ([db_pki].[dbo].[Maker].[Code_maker] = [db_pki].[dbo].[Accounts].[Code_maker])
)date_to_pivot
PIVOT 
(
Max([Quan])
For [Tasknum]
IN (' + @task + ')
 )AS p'
Execute (@query)
```

Comment: The only problem is that the sum of the fields "quan_arr" and "quan_accs" is more than real.

Comment: It seems because of the fact that in tables "accounts" and "arrival" can be more than 1 record.

Comment: @user1613291: Yes, I think I can see the problem. Two or more of your joins result in more than one row per match, effectively giving you mini-[Cartesian products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product "Cartesian product (Wikipedia)"). This kind of issue sometimes happens to me too. Apparently you need to figure out how to join/filter your tables properly to avoid duplicates in the intermediate result set (the resulting set of the joins) before moving on to aggregating/pivoting.